# How to identify the dataset as a time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, time-series

I am working on an automated tool where it have to support all kinds of data. Without looking at the data, are there any methods to identify that the dataset following time series? Are there any statistical tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the data set if you find data points are equally spaced then your data is time series data.

Ex:continuous monitoring of a person’s heart rate, hourly readings of air temperature, daily closing price of a company stock, monthly rainfall data, and yearly sales figures.

Comment: so if I have daily sales data where the data is not evenly spaces but rather uneven. Will it still be a time series data or not?

Comment: if its daily sales data then its time series data. If some data is missing in some point of time then we need to treat that missing data.